# tunnel port 8080 over jumpserver using ssh - socks5 proxy?

Tags: web-server, ssh-tunnel, dmz, socks

I have this setup:

LocalPC - Jumpserver - Webserver with page only accessible on this machine via

```
localhost:8080
```

LocalPC and Webserver are not connected - Jumpserver has to be used.
Jumpserver doesn't have access to the Webpage on Webserver

I want to use Firefox to view this webpage on LocalPC.

I know how to make socks proxy to Jumpserver - normally this is enough but not in this case

```
ssh -TD 8080 me@jumpserver
```

and

I know how to tunnel one specific port over Jumpserver

```
ssh -f -N -q -L 2222:me@target:22 me@jumpserver
```

But using the first method only makes a tunnel to Jumpserver and using the second method with ports 8081:me@webserver:8080 doesn't give error but results in 404 for

```
http://localhost:8081
```

in firefox...

So how will I see the website on LocalPC?

And for security reasons:
I need both connections encrypted and let no other users on Jumpserver use the tunnel.

(Sry for codeblocks - I am not allowed to write word localhost...)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know that you could daisy chain ssh tunnels but I just tried it out & it works just fine. This is my test environment

1. 192.168.1.10 (HearNoEvil) Browser
2. 192.168.1.20 (SeeNoEvil) Piggy in the middle
3. 192.168.1.30 (SpeakNoEvil) Server

Daisy chains looks like this

> 1. Tunnel
>
> 192.168.1.30:8080 <->  192.168.1.20:8081
>
> SeeNoEvil:~# ssh -f -L 8081:127.0.0.1:8080 user@SpeakNoEvil -N
>
> 2. Tunnel
>
> 192.168.1.20:8081 <-> 192.168.1.10:8082
>
> HearNoEvil:~# ssh -f -L 8082:127.0.0.1:8081 root@SeeNoEvil -N
>
> Socks Proxy 127.0.0.1:8082
>
> https://HearNoEvil.testy.test:8082

I'm working of course backwards for the outside in & SpeakNoEvil is my Server. HearNoEvil being my browser. Hope this was helpful. (^_^)

Comment: Will everybody on "SeeNoEvil" be able to use this tunnel or is it just me? Just asking for security reasons...

Comment: Ok I figured out everybody actually can use this tunnel - so I can't do it this way - but it works.

Comment: By using 127.0.0.1 as the address you have effectively started a service which is only reachable from localhost. So the answer would have to be every user on SeeNoEvil will have access to this local service.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found my solution with help of the first answer to this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010808/ssh-tunnelling-chain#1122282

If I build this tunnel chains in ssh-config I can then use ssh -TD 8080 webserver and build a dynamic tunnel. Then I just have to add 127.0.0.1:8080 as socks5 proxy in Firefox and be happy.